# I need adminstrator privileges to move file (node.js)

Tags: node.js

I am making custom installer for my program by node.js

I need to move unzipped file to "C:\Program Files\Program Name", but I can't move because I don't have permission.

Can I get administrator privileges in node.js?

```js
module.exports.mv = function (source, dest) {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       mv(source, dest, {mkdirp: true}, function (err) {
           if (err) reject(err);
           resolve();
       });
   });
}
```

I used ["mv"](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mv) module.

Comment: Start a powershell terminal with Run as Administrator privileges.

Comment: Is not it always outside of the scope of the program and user should call your program with special role/rights?

Comment: It's installer of my program, so I need get admin privileges on run packaged program. @Danizavtz

Comment: I would recommend using wixtoolset (open source tool) for creating a windows installer msi or exe. @Tilto_